# Problem with DIY Smart Glasses Projection module

Tags: pi-3, gpio, hardware, display, connection

I am making Smart glasses which will display android app, click pictures, notifications and many more, and which is to be displayed on a small prism I searched a lot of posts online, many of then suggested me to use Kopin BDM-922k projector LCD but they have stopped the production of that module. 
I am so confused what to do for projection. At the end came up a basic solution of using LCD display then use mirrors and displaying it on Prism, this idea is used by a lot of people but i don't know what to do. Please help me out this is my graduation project and want it to be best.

I thought of using this TFT display but unable to figure out how to connect it with raspberry pi 3 or 4.

- 0.96" Mini IPS TFT LCD Display

  [image]

Comment: Check [this link](https://www.buydisplay.com/spi-tft-0-96-inch-lcd-display-module-160x80-ips-st7735-with-arduino-library) out. Datasheets and Documents are there.

Comment: This question does not appear to be specific to the Raspberry Pi within the scope defined in the [help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).